# How to create local SQL Server database with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have Microsoft imagine with azure, Visual Studio 2017 (SQL Server installed) etc. I can create a free (basic) database server with 5 DTU that Microsoft offers me, but I prefer to create a local one on my computer. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can still download a free copy of SQL Server Express from Microsoft.

Comment: I just did, but i didn't install it yet. I am a totally begginer with SQL and i am just trying to practise some basic sql commands with Visual Studio. Generally, what do i have to do know with SQL server express after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Please download for free SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition or SQL Server 2017 Express Edition from **[here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)**.

Comment: I have no idea why your answer was downvoted. Both yours and tillerman35's are correct.

Comment: What I am doing helping others in this site and other forums is considered to me an act of love to everyone needing help. For many years now I have decided to separate myself from negative things and only see only the positive side of everything. Please ignore this kind of things. Enjoy this day, enjoy life.

Comment: Well said, Alberto. As for the negative reception to the original question, I think that some StackOverflow members are unnecessarily harsh with new users who aren't familiar with the format here, with beginners, and with non-native English speakers. If someone asks a well-intentioned question that doesn't fit the guidelines, people should have the courtesy to explain to the original poster how things work. Downvoting someone with no explanation who is obviously new is not very welcoming.

Comment: People often overlook the power a single act of kindness. How many people exist demanding attention, hoping somebody can "see" them ... Let's accept that people have different levels of evolution. Let's think we all have the same essence. Let's rest assure  that God cannot be wrong and all we see is perfection made by him. Let's let it go.

Comment: Seriously, i am really disapointed and agry with Stackoverflow community. That's why i rarely post questions here. Because there are always some people who are doing like trolls and downvote everything without a reason even if someone did helped someone else. They don't appreciate the willingness and the time someone put to help someone. Plus, this prevents me to ask more questions and help me get used to how this forum works...i just want to said all these.